# Omit array from sql query

Tags: php, sql

I am displaying a list of "absent players" from my site, and currently have only omitted the "admin" username from displaying in the list. I have added an array of "inactive players", but am not sure how to omit that array from the sql query as well.

Here is the code:

```
//display list of absent players
$sql = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "users where userID not in(" . implode(',', array_keys($playerTotals)) . ") and userName <> 'admin'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $absentHtml = '<p style="color: #7a7a7a; position: relative"><b>Absent Players:</b> ';
    $i = 0;
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if ($i > 0) $absentHtml .= ', ';
        switch ($user_names_display) {
            case 1:
                $absentHtml .= trim($result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname']);
                break;
            case 2:
                $absentHtml .= $result['userName'];
                break;
            default: //3
                $absentHtml .= '<abbrev title="' . trim($result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname']) . '">' . $result['userName'] . '</abbrev>';
                break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo $absentHtml;
```

The array, located elsewhere, looks like this:

```
//list of inactive users
$inactiveUsers = array('user1','user2','user3');
```

As you can see, `and userName <> 'admin'` omits the "admin" name, but I have no clue as how to also add the array $inactiveUsers to that as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$sql = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "users where userID not in(" . implode(',', array_keys($playerTotals)) . ") and userName not in(" . implode(',', $inactiveUsers) . ", admin)";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "select * from ".$db_prefix."users
where userID not in (".implode(',', array_keys($playerTotals)).")
and userName not in ('admin', '".implode("','", $inactiveUsers)."')";
```